# Angular build causing an error.- FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular

When I am trying to execute

```
ng build my.sample.application --prod=false --configuration=dev
```

I get the error shown below. To overcome this issue I have executed

```
node --max_old_space_size=15000
```

command too but the issue still persists.

Error

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
>   1: 00007FF6F564094F napi_wrap+124431
>   2: 00007FF6F55E2696 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+34502
>   3: 00007FF6F55E3356 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+37766
>    4: 00007FF6F5DE6F4E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
>    5: 00007FF6F5DCEF91 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
>    6: 00007FF6F5C9C85C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
>    7: 00007FF6F5CA7C00 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
>    8: 00007FF6F5CA4734 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
>    9: 00007FF6F5C99FC3 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
>   10: 00007FF6F5C98794 v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap+2356
>   11: 00007FF6F5CC0787 v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString+87
>   12: 00007FF6F5AE797C v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten+492
>   13: 00007FF6F59B110F unibrow::Utf8::EncodeOneByte+687
>   14: 00007FF6F5DF13A6 v8::String::Utf8Length+22
>   15: 00007FF6F55FCE0C v8::internal::Malloced::operator delete+14476
>   16: 00007FF6F5D9B150 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+325536
>   17: 00007FF6F5D9A697 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+322791
>   18: 00007FF6F5D9A9D8 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323624
>   19: 00007FF6F5D9A7DE v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323118
>   20: 00007FF6F6212D6D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+568205
>   21: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   22: 00007FF6F618BBAC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+14796
>   23: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   24: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   25: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   26: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   27: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   28: 00007FF6F618BBAC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+14796
>   29: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   30: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   31: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   32: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   33: 00007FF6F618BBAC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+14796
>   34: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   35: 00007FF6F618BBAC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+14796
>   36: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   37: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   38: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   39: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   40: 00007FF6F61927FC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+42524
>   41: 00007FF6F618BBAC v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+14796
>   42: 00007FF6F618FDB1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31697
>   43: 00007FF6F618F99C v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+30652
>   44: 00007FF6F5CF4F43 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1395
>   45: 00007FF6F5CF48C6 v8::internal::Execution::Call+182
>   46: 00007FF6F5DC5B3B v8::Function::Call+603
>   47: 00007FF6F565CA45 node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+1429
>   48: 00007FF6F5655FE3 v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeNode::operand_scale+179
>   49: 00007FF6F55DFBB3 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+23523
>   50: 00007FF6F55D4FE1 EVP_CIPHER_CTX_buf_noconst+200753
>   51: 00007FF6F568CFC7 uv_timer_stop+775
>   52: 00007FF6F5689AAB uv_async_send+331
>   53: 00007FF6F568924C uv_loop_init+1212
>   54: 00007FF6F5689414 uv_run+244
>   55: 00007FF6F55AB892 EVP_CIPHER_CTX_buf_noconst+30946
>   56: 00007FF6F5609263 node::Start+275
>   57: 00007FF6F54C666C RC4_options+339308
>   58: 00007FF6F62C5D58 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1301368
>   59: 00007FFB974A13D2 BaseThreadInitThunk+34
>   60: 00007FFB977654F4 RtlUserThreadStart+52
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you run it with this command: `node --max_old_space_size=15000 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build...`?

Comment: Thank you @David, your suggestion worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use
"build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=prod", in your package.json file
1

this will tell node to exceed default memory allocation by given size in command.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue compiling Angular 10, however in my case the issue was an incorrect version of node.  My node version was 10.15.1 and once I switched back to node version 13.14.0 the issue was resolved.  I use nvm (Node Version Manager) to switch between versions of node so I can still run Angular 7/8 projects and forgot to switch it back.

Hope this helps someone with the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I came acorss similar issue

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

in Package.json

--max_old_space_size=4096 should not exceed your RAM memory, this is causing this error I guess.

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "rtl": "webpack",
  },
```